# How to Send Emails to Subscribed Users in Django or How to send News Letters in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying how can I send mass mails to the Subscribed Users. I have the E-mails of the User and want them to send News Letters or anything else. But, I am unable to do these.
So Help me by the Explanation and providing CODE.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Hi Pritish. Stackoverflow works best when you tried to work on the problem and you unable to do so and then you post here with the code snippet and we jump into giving the solution. How about that?

Comment: I have tried doing it. But I am completely blank how to do these how can we send emails to subscribe users.

Comment: How about we start with what you've in `models.py` file?